# sed regular expression doesn't consider double quote or white space

Tags: regex, unix, sed

Following sed command with regex does not work properly, I want to remove the host element but it also remove the next element

sed command

```
sed -i 's+^\(.*SERVER.*\)\(host=.*\)[[:blank:]]\(.*/>.*\)$+\1\3+' /tmp/file_tmp.xml
```

/tmp/file_tmp.xml

```
  <SERVER port="2001" buildg="group1" host="host1" slices="1" search="st0"/>
  <SERVER port="2003" buildg="group2" host="" slices="1" search="st1"/>
```

expected output:

```
  <SERVER port="2001" buildg="group1" slices="1" search="st0"/>
  <SERVER port="2003" buildg="group2" slices="1" search="st1"/>
```

Actual output

```
  <SERVER port="2001" buildg="group1" search="st0"/>
  <SERVER port="2003" buildg="group2" search="st1"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.*` is greedy (it matches the longest possible string), so the one in `host=.*[[:blank:]]` catches all up to (not inclusive) `search`. Try this instead:

```
sed 's+^\(.*SERVER.*\)\(host=[^ ]*\)[[:blank:]]\(.*/>.*\)$+\1\3+'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple `sed` solution.

1. Find the line of interest using grep pattern ``
2. Remove the required RegExp string in found line.

   ```
   sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*<SERVER/s| host="[^"]*"||' input.txt
   ```

#### Explanation

`/^[[:space:]]*<SERVER/` Filter only line staring with spaces and SERVER

`s| host="[^"]*"||` Substitute RegExp `host="[^"]*"` with empty string.

`host="[^"]*"` RegExp to match `name"*"`

Comment: `/[[:space:]]*<SERVER/` does not match a string that *starts* with spaces and `<SERVER`, you need `^` at the start for that to happen, `/^[[:space:]]*<SERVER/`